# upload xml file without encoding

Tags: php, html, xml

I would like to upload xml file via HTML form.
I have .xml file but there is no header like : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`

My file xml:

```
<wocand>
<roz>
<lp>1</lp>
<sign>I SA/Go 420/19</sign>
<date>08:30</date>
<simb>6550</simb>
<item>123</item>
</roz>
<roz>
<lp>2</lp>
<sign>I SA/Go 430/19</sign>
<date>09:30</date>
<simb>6750</simb>
<item>163</item>
</roz>
...
<wocand>
```

My html/php form:

```
<form id="importFile" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="fileToImport" type="file" name="wocan" class="btn" accept="text/xml" required>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

<?php
 if( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) )
 {

       if( isset( $_FILES['wocan'] ) && ( $_FILES['wocan']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) )
       {
           $file = simplexml_load_file( $_FILES['wocan']['tmp_name'] );
           print_r( $file );  // <-- testing porpose
       }
       else
           echo 'Error: '. $_FILES['wocan']['error'];
 }
```

I turn on `error_reporting`

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And there is an error:

`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): /tmp/php85UNT1:7: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xEA 0x64 0x7A 0x69 in /public_html/wocan/importWocan.php on line 41`

How can i upload this file via html and read it in PHP.
I tried:

```
simplexml_load_file( $_FILES['wocan']['tmp_name']);
```

I even once edited the xml file and added the first line `<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?>` (this is not corret encoding but w/e) and it worked! But the user will not be able to add it manually, besides he will have to load a dozen or so such files a day so he cannot edit this file before uploading.

So there is a problem with simplexml_load_file because it cannot load 'xml' file without encoding.

Can I read this file differently?
Or can I add line with encoding to this file in PHP?
Maybe i need to read it as txt, but then I don't know how I could make an array from it.

Comment: Does the contents of `$_FILES['wocan']['tmp_name']` match the expected content.

Comment: content of xml file is in question. File is uploading but there is a problem with `simplexml_load_file` because it cannot load 'xml' file without encoding

Comment: _"(this is not corret encoding but w/e)"_ - OK, so what _is_ the correct encoding of the document you are uploading?

Comment: The XML declaration is only optional if the encoding is UTF-8 … since it isn't the XML is broken … and you should fix whatever is creating it in the first place.

Comment: I don't know what is the correct encoding. It should has polish characters but when im trying to use utf-8 or iso-8859-2 it doesn't work anyway. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for keeping me on track.

The `.xml` file was encoded in ANSI unknown encoding.
After the 'save as' action (UTF8 encoding) the file import and read are correct.
Maybe it will help someone.

However, I could not change the encoding of the file in PHP.

Comment: This is expected. Your XML missed the declaration of the encoding. So the loader/parser falls back to its defaults. Your actual XML contents does not match the default encoding, resulting in a conflict. Basically if your serialized, encoded XML string is anything except ASCII it should declare its encoding.